# Lookup multiple rows for a single term

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet table that looks like this:

**Table: Group Info**

```
Group ID    Location    Leader 1 Leader 2 Leader 3
--------------------------------------------------
Antelope    C7          Anne     Brenda   Carol
Billygoat   C8          Derek    Edgar    -
Cantaloupe  B3          Georgie  Hilda    -
...
```

The Group Info table lists information about each group according to the Group ID.

And in another table:

**Table: Leader Info**

```
Group ID    Leader      Email
--------------------------------------------------
Antelope    Anne        anne12@example.com
Antelope    Brenda      brenda@example.com
Antelope    Carol       carol.s@example.com
Billygoat   Derek       derek@example.com
...
```

The Leader Info table lists information about the leaders, including which Group ID they belong to.

What I'd lke to do is to be able to use the second table (Leader Info) to populate the first (Group Info) in the "Leader 1", "Leader 2", "Leader 3" columns. I know that each `Group ID` wil have at most 3 leaders, but possibly less.

Is there a way to look up the "Leader 1", "Leader 2", "Leader 3" columns from the Leader Info table?

Comment: your tags seem contradictory. Do you use Excel or G-S ?

Comment: @iDevlop I tagged both because I'd like to know how to achieve this in both Excel and Google sheets. I wasn't aware that this combination wasn't kosher..?

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is like this:

Add two helper columns to the Leader Info table, one as the first column (A), which is the "Leader ID", and one somewhere else (for the sake of example I'll use column B), which is the "Leader Number" within the group. Group ID at this stage is column C.

**Table: Leader Info**

```
[A]               [B]           [C]        [D]     
Leader ID         Leader Number Group ID   Leader  ...
---------------------------------------------------
                                Antelope   Anne    ...
                                Antelope   Brenda  ...
                                ...
```

The Leader Number is to be the cumulative count of the the Group ID in the table. I use a `countif` for this:

**Cell B2:** `=countif(C$2:C2, C2)`

This searches everything from the top of the Group ID column for matches to the current Group ID and returns the total count from this row and before. Copy that formula down the column.

The Leader ID is a way to group the Group ID and the Leader Number.

**Cell A2:** `=concatenate(C2, " Leader ", B2)`

So the resulting Leader Info table looks like this:

**Table: Leader Info**

```
[A]               [B]           [C]        [D]     
Leader ID         Leader Number Group ID   Leader  ...
---------------------------------------------------
Antelope Leader 1             1 Antelope   Anne    ...
Antelope Leader 2             2 Antelope   Brenda  ...
Antelope Leader 3             3 Antelope   Carol   ...
Billygoat Leader 1            1 Billygoat  Derek   ...
...
```

Then, the Group Info table can look up the appropriate Leader ID. Given this set up:

**Table: Group Info**

```
[A]         [B]         [C]      [D]      [E]
Group ID    Location    Leader 1 Leader 2 Leader 3
--------------------------------------------------
Antelope    C7
Billygoat   C8
Cantaloupe  B3
...
```

We put this formula in the Leader columns:

**Cell C2:** `=vlookup(concatenate($A2, " ", C$1), LeaderInfo, 4, FALSE)`

That's almost good, but there's a lookup fail if the second or third leader doesn't exist. So I use `iferror` to display a dash if the entry doesn't exist.

**Cell C2:** `=iferror(vlookup(concatenate($A2," ",C$1), LeaderInfo, 4, FALSE), "-")`

Copy that to all cells in columns C, D, and E, and the result is as desired!

**Table: Group Info**

```
Group ID    Location    Leader 1 Leader 2 Leader 3
--------------------------------------------------
Antelope    C7          Anne     Brenda   Carol
Billygoat   C8          Derek    Edgar    -
Cantaloupe  B3          Georgie  Hilda    -
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could also do (on first sheet)
=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Sheet2!$B$2:$B, Sheet2!$A$2:$A = $A2)))
where sheet2 is the 'lookup' sheet and B is the col on sheet 2 that holds
the names. Drag down as far as needed.

See if that helps ?